# Phonegap build / cordova overwrite my icon and put default icon to device :-(

Tags: android, cordova, icons, phonegap-build, platform

I can't solve my Problem, maybe someone can help.

What I did:

1. put some code to my config.xml , like in the documentation here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html
2. I changed all the icons and screens.
3. rm the android platform and add it again to my project.
4. After building the android platform, the icons are all correct in the 
   folder..... platforms/android/res/**drawable**  , platforms/android/res/**drawable-hdpi** and so on....
5. Than I build my app with phonegap build.
6. On device (Android 4.0.1) they are still showing the default icons :-(

Do phonegap build ignore my Icons? - and why?

Code I put to my config.xml

```
 <!--   app icon . -->
 <platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/icon.png"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
 </platform>


 <!--  splash screen . -->
 <platform name="android"> 

    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>

</platform>
```

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution for me, maybe it helps also other people. The icons and also splashscreen now works. The important Change was to use this line `<icon   src="res/icon.png" />`  for show icons. For screen you can try this `<gap:splash src="res/screen.png" />`

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />


<feature name="PushPlugin">
   <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" />
</feature>   


<!--   app icon . -->
<icon   src="res/icon.png" />

 <platform name="android">  
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"  density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"  density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"  density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
 </platform>


 <!--  splash screen . -->
 <gap:splash src="res/screen.png" />

 <platform name="android">  
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png"  density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png"  density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png"  density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/> 
</platform>
```